# Codegear Rad Studio C++Builder 2007 won't open on Windows XP SP2

Tags: ide, rad-studio

I've been using Rad Studio for some old projects on another Windows XP (32 bit) based PC. So, I wanted to move my projects new computer. But, after the setup, bds.exe didn't open. Same setup file works on Windows 10 PC (64 bit), but I am not able to open on Windows XP computer.

When I tried to open its closing immediately and giving just-in-time debug option from visual studio 2005. Also, it’s giving some error codes. But, I couldn’t find any solution for this issue.
When I wanted to open firstly following screen comes up.
[image: Just-In Time Debugger]

Then, if I click no it’s closing. If I click yes following screen comes up.
[image: Error codes]

Note: Closing Just-in-time debug doesn’t help to open bds.exe .